# Remove a li element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to remove a li element when I click on it. At first the code work fine, then when I put in my project, the remove function is not working. I put my code on fiddle and nothing work anymore. I search all the web and try to fix but nothing works, please explain to me cause I still new to jquery & java script.

Here is my code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyrzbvwe/

My HTML would like:

```
<ul class="listcheckbox">
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk1">9-10g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk2">10-11g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk3">11-12g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk4" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk4">12-13g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk5" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk5">13-14g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk6" name="timetable" />
    <label for="chk6" class="item">14-15g <span class="pull-right"></span>

    </label>
</li>
```

Here the script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[name="timetable"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#timeselect').append($('<li class="clearfix delete">' + $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text() + '<img src="delete.png" class="pull-right" /></a></li>'));
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('#timeselect').on('click', 'li.delete', function () {
    var time = $(this).text().trim();
    var idTime = '#' + $('label').filter(function () {
        return this.firstChild.nodeValue.trim() === time;
    }).attr('for');

    $(idTime).prop('checked', false);
    $(idTime).attr('disabled', false);

    $(this).remove();
});
});
```

Comment: Your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ghkonrb9/

Comment: You havent selected jQuery :)

Comment: In the fiddle you havent selected the jquery and I think in your project also you might have not added jquery.Check in the browser console and find out if you get any errors

Comment: You have to include JQuery library as mentioned by @Joakim M in your jsfiddle or project before your javascript file.

Comment: As my friends are saying you must include the js library....now click on this its working   .....http://jsfiddle.net/cyrzbvwe/3/

Comment: @SpringLearner: Oh thanks so much, I included like you say and it works fine, but can you help me out with this: I insert some html below and jquery is not working anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/ddheLqvx/

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of null"

Use F12 to debug your code

Comment: @NhuelNeo WHAT IS THE PROBLEM IN THE FIDDLE?

Comment: @SpringLearner: Sorry for not explain the problem clearly. Here the simplier code: http://jsfiddle.net/ptrpzvLv/. The remove function works fine until I add some other checkboxs below.

Comment: @JoakimM: Thanks soooo much... I debug and got what is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @JoakimM and @PpringLearner's comment. It's turn out I forgot to include jquery in jsFiddle

But the problem I came in is when I add more checkbox with label, remove function is not working again. Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ptrpzvLv/

I debug like @JoakimM said, and it's turn out some label element contain no Value so trim() function got error and stops there...

What I've done is make it's more clear at this line `var idTime = '#' + $('label').filter` to `var idTime = '#' + $('ul.listcheckbox label').filter`

p/s: I really appriciate all of your help.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the coding!